# Getting behavior around 0 for spectrum of product of Gaussian matrices?

Tags: probability-or-statistics, linear-algebra

**Edit** the math part was [answered](https://mathoverflow.net/a/450956/7655) in mathoverflow, I'm now looking on how to port this to Mathematica to check against observed fit

Consider a product of $k$ independent square matrices with IID standard normal entries. How do I find the asymptotic behavior of spectrum around 0?

`Asymptotic[CDF[MarchenkoPasturDistribution[1], x], x -> 0]` tells me that CDF of squared singular values is $O(\sqrt{x})$ for $k=1$. I'm looking for similar expressions for other values of $k$. Visualization below suggests it is a power law.

```
ClearAll["Global`*"];

genCDF[coefs_] :=
  {Sort@coefs, Range@Length@coefs/Length[coefs]}\[Transpose];

SF = StringForm;
n = 1000;
randMat[iters_] := 
  With[{sample := 
     RandomVariate[NormalDistribution[], {n, n}]/Sqrt[n]}, 
   Nest[# . sample &, sample, iters - 1]];
sf = None;
sf = {"Log", "Log"};
productVals = Range[3];
legends = SF["k=``", #] & /@ productVals;
x0 = 10^-6;
Show[
 Plot[(2 Sqrt[x])/\[Pi], {x, x0, 4},
  PlotTheme -> "Detailed", PlotStyle -> {Red, Dashed}, 
  PlotLegends -> {"\!\(\*FractionBox[\(2\\\ \*SqrtBox[\(x\)]\), \(\
\[Pi]\)]\)"}, Exclusions -> None, ScalingFunctions -> sf],
 ListPlot[
  Table[genCDF[SingularValueList[randMat[k]]^2], {k, productVals}], 
  ScalingFunctions -> sf, PlotLegends -> legends],
 PlotLabel -> 
  "CDF of singular values of product of k Gaussian matrices"
 ]
```

[image]

Comment: The pointwise product or power of matrices is a strange object, as it does not fit into any scheme of chains of linear maps.  As a discretization of a continuous Gaussian it looks like $$e^{(-n(x^2/2\sigma ^2)})/(2 \pi \sigma^2)^{n/2}$$

Comment: @RolandF I was looking at regular matrix product though.

Comment: Was the answer from [here](https://mathoverflow.net/questions/450955/spectrum-asymptotics-for-a-product-of-k-random-matrices/450956#450956) relevant at all to this question? I thought maybe adding links to the mathoverflow and the [math.SE](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/4737370/singular-values-of-random-matrix-with-iid-entries) questions to the bottom of this question may help so we have all the information of what's currently been done with this problem. Maybe this was a completely different question though

Comment: Reason for collecting all the information: I have a former colleague who works on random matrix theory to forward this question to. He may have time to look at this and have some insights. I found some interesting stuff myself using `FindDistributionParameters` but the fits are not good quality: Calling (for any integer k>0) `FindDistributionParameters[SingularValueList[randMat[k]]^2, 
 MarchenkoPasturDistribution[lambda, k]]`
always yields `lambda->1.`
but the fit does not appear to be good, so I think `1.` for the first parameter in `MarchenkoPasturDistribution` might be the default value

Comment: @ydd yes, this answer was pretty relevant, I just need to work through the notation to figure out how to implement those formulas in Mathematica and compare with the fit

Comment: Looks like exact formula for squared singular value density of a product of $n$ matrices is Eq 3.61 of Ipsen [thesis](https://arxiv.org/pdf/1510.06128.pdf), hard edge asymptotic is 3.62